# Tutorial for the WGCNA: changes in heatmap colours

Tags: rna-seq, wgcna

I am trying to reproduce the results of the R tutorial of the WGCNA package.

In section I number 5, when generating the heatmap it is quite similar to the one provided by the pdf but the colours of the heatmap differ from the document. Is it possible to change it?

I attach the image together with the code used.

[[image: image obtained]

Image Obtained

[image: image of tutorial]

Image of tutorial

```r
nSelect = 400
set.seed(10);
select = sample(nGenes, size = nSelect);
selectTOM = dissTOM[select, select];
selectTree = hclust(as.dist(selectTOM), method = "average")
selectColors = moduleColors[select];
sizeGrWindow(9,9)
plotDiss = selectTOM^7;
diag(plotDiss) = NA;
TOMplot(plotDiss, selectTree, selectColors, main = "Network heatmap plot, selected genes")
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the WGCNA tutorial?

Comment: Please consider the answer by @CorteZero - looks fine to me - and consider upvoting/accepting. Accepting an answer does help with site stats

Answer (score 1):

You can add a color palette to the plot.

e.g.

```r
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "orange", "yellow","white"))(n = 100);
TOMplot(plotDiss, selectTree, selectColors, main ="Network heatmap plot, selected genes", col=my_palette)
```